# Possible deadlock graph for 3 threads and 2 resources

Tags: multithreading, graph, process, resources, deadlock

let's say we have 3 threads (T1, T2, T3) which share 2 resources (R1, R2). My question is if all of 3 threads can be on blocked on deadlock at the same time. If yes, what is a possible graph that represents this deadlock?
What I have thought is the following:

**T1 gets R1**

**T2 gets R2**

**T1 asks for R2**

**T2 asks for R1 (DEADLOCK!)**

**T3 asks for R2 (ALL THREADS ARE NOW BLOCKED!)**

A simple graph corresponding to this flow of events is the following

[image]

Is that right? Can T2 and T3 ask for R2 at the same time in order all threads to be blocked?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course.  Just as T1 and T2 asked for it.

Comment: Look at your graph. It contains cycle R1-T1-R2-T2-R1. Loops on a resource graph demonstrate deadlocks.

Comment: Okay, one more question: If we had only 1 resource could then a deadlock occur?

Comment: Yes. For example, using read-write-lock.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how can this happen?

Comment: A copy program which was given the same path as input and output. T1 reads the first line of the given file and sends it to T2 which does some indexing with it or whatever. After that T2 give the string to T3 which tries to write into the file but has to wait since T1 still neads the ressource to get the next line of text. Technically there isn't a direct cycle, since T2 doesn't allocate any resource but it still ends in an deadlock.